# C, When I change the character in a single position of a 2D array a second positon also has its character changed

Tags: c, arrays, character

I have just started learning C a day ago so apologies if the answer is obvious, or my code is terribly inefficient.

I am creating a battleship game where 3 ships (a battleship, a destroyer, and a carrier) will be placed onto a board.

The battleship will occupy 3 squares, the destroyer 2, and the carrier 5.

The board is a 2 dimensional array of characters

```
    P1_board[9][9]
```

When a player wishes to place a ship on the board specific positions in the array will be changed to a character ('B' for battleship, 'D' for destroyer, and 'C' for carrier). A ship is placed onto the board through a subroutine called:

```
    PlaceShip(char Letter, char Number, char Ship, char Direction)
```

Where Letter will be a lowercase character from a to j, Number will be a number character from 1 to 10, Ship will be either 'B','D', or 'C' for the corresponding ship, and Direction will be either 'r' for right or 'd' for down.

The problem I have is that when I try to place a ship on either the left or rand edges a position on the opposite side of the board is also changed.

Example:
When I run these C commands:

```
    PlaceShip('a', '2', 'C', 'r');
    PlaceShip('a', '7', 'B', 'd');
```

[Image: Carrier supposed to occupy a2 to e2 and battleship supposed to occupy a7 to a9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXkgY.png)

If I now instead run these C commands:

```
    PlaceShip('c', '2', 'C', 'r');
    PlaceShip('b', '7', 'B', 'd');
```

[Image: the ships are away from the edges and no characters appear on opposite sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqBPO.png)

I thought that it could maybe be some sought of character overflowing into the next array position but i'm not sure how to fix that or if this is even the case.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 edition's Visual C++ to compile and run C code.

Below is the a simplified version of my full code which still produces the problem:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define Board_Size 2
    Board[Board_Size][Board_Size];
    void main() {
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= Board_Size; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <=Board_Size; j++) {
                    Board[i][j] = 'a';
                    printf("%c   ", Board[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    Board[0][2] = 'b';
    //   [y][x]
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c   %c   %c\n", Board[0][0], Board[0][1], Board[0][2]);
    printf("%c   %c   %c\n", Board[1][0], Board[1][1], Board[1][2]);
    printf("%c   %c   %c\n", Board[2][0], Board[2][1], Board[2][2]);
    }
```

Comment: Full code here: http://pastebin.com/hPRW9cd3

Comment: `int y = Number - 49;    //'1'=int(49)` ? Are you sure you want to convert `'1'` into `0`?

Comment: that is so that when a user types the battleship coords "a1" the '1' gets converted from character '1' to integer 0 so that it can be used to address the first row of the array

Comment: the code should be checking to assure the position is within the bounds of the board.   One simple easement is to actually define the board somewhat larger than the playing area.  say 12x12 for the 9x9 playing area.

Comment: I hope you do understand how memory is actually laid out when using an array.  If not, then that might be a good place to start when trying to understand the source of the problem

Comment: Ill try making the board 12x12 with a playing area 9x9 now

Comment: I made the board 14x14 to give 2 spaces padding on each side, I no longer get the extra characters appearing on the board.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, Ill create the shortest code now

Comment: In your code above `#define Board_Size 4` and `char Board[Board_Size][Board_Size];` create a 2D array with indexes `0-3` (for each dimension). `Board[4][x]` and `Board[x][4]` write beyond the end of the array invoking *undefined behavior*. Also, `10` is *two characters* unless you are storing `'\n'` (see [**ASCIItable**](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines.

Comment: the return type from `main()` is always `int`, even on a board that has no OS

Comment: this function: `int ArrCoordX(char Letter)` should check that the passed in character is >= 'a' before subtracting 97 from its' value

Comment: when writing a `switch()` statement, there should (almost) always be a `default` case, just to handle any unexpected input to the function.

Comment: just as a heads up, the `switch()` statement is expecting a `int` not a char

Comment: Generally, it is a good idea to observe the width of a sheet of paper (makes printing the source listing much neater) when writing lines of code

Comment: regarding all those calls to `printf()` that output the current board state Suggest using nested loops rather than accessing each field individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line #7 (referring to your linked code).  It's a simple mistake and a common one in languages with 0-based arrays where you often have to subtract one from the size to determine the upper bound.

You declare "Board_Size" as being 10 but subtract one to get a 9x9 matrix:

> #define Board_Size 10 
>   char P1_board[Board_Size - 1][Board_Size - 1];

This prints a 10x10 matrix:

> printf("  1 |  %c |  %c |  %c |  %c |  %c |  %c |  %c |  %c |  %c |  %c |\n", P1_board[0][0], P1_board[0][1], P1_board[0][2], P1_board[0][3], P1_board[0][4], P1_board[0][5], P1_board[0][6], P1_board[0][7], P1_board[0][8], P1_board[0][9]);

C stores arrays in row-major order (and for a 9x9 matrix element A(0,10) is in the same memory location as element A(1,0), and that explains why you see multiple ships on the board.

As an aside, C treats character constants as integers, so you can write (letter - 'a') to convert a letter to an index.

WIkipedia has a nice description of what row-major order means if you're not familiar with the term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: I think I get it now

if I want to define a 10x10 array I do this:
`char Board[10][10];`
but if I want to access the 10th entry on the 10th column I do this:
`Board[9][9] = 'a';`

Is this correct?

Comment: That is exactly right.  Indexes start from zero, the maximum index is (size -1), but sizes are always sizes in a declaration.